# Session sharing is not working from privileged class in os x

Tags: swift, macos, singleton, data-sharing

I'm working on an os x app that deals with the user keychain in mac os.
I have a Singleton class that manages the session data, and a privileged mechanism(which doesn't have any GUI). I want to share the data from the privileged class through Singleton object. But it's not working.
Here is my code sample

```
The Privileged Class:



 class ReadKeychain: AuthorizationContext {
     @objc func run(){
         var singletonObj = SingletonState.shared
         singletonObj.oktaAuthenticationStatus = status
      }
    }
```

And The singleton class object:

```
class SingletonState {
    
    static let shared = SingletonState()
    
    private init(){}
    
    private let internalQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.tecmfa.singletonstateinternal.queue",
                                              qos: .default,
                                              attributes: .concurrent)
    private struct _oktaAuthentication
    {
        var status: String?
    }

    private var OktaAuthStatus = _oktaAuthentication()
    
    /// oktaAuthentication reference
    var oktaAuthenticationStatus: String {
        get {
            return internalQueue.sync {
                return OktaAuthStatus.status!
            }
        }
        set (newStatus) {
            internalQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
                self.OktaAuthStatus.status = newStatus
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- And it is working fine if I declare the class as unprivileged
- But I need it to be privileged

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it’s related to the issue, but.
You've got a potential force-unwrap-induced crash here.

It happens when the value for `oktaAuthenticationStatus` hasn't yet been set, but already gets read. I suggest you change the type of this variable to optional and remove the force-unwrap:

```swift
var oktaAuthenticationStatus: String? {
    get {
        return internalQueue.sync {
            return OktaAuthStatus.status
        }
    }
    set (newStatus) {
        internalQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
            self.OktaAuthStatus.status = newStatus
        }
    }
}
```

Or better yet, if you have a small number of statuses, make it an enum and add an option like `.none` for it to be the default value. Then the variable won't be optional.

Comment: Thanks for answering... @AntonBarok  Actually I did try it.. But that doesn't work and When I make the other class as unprivileged, it's working fine!!